# onClickListener() for view obstructed by children

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-tablelayout

I have TableLayout where I add rows dynamically.

For each one I want to add an onClickListener() that does row selection things, let's say highlights the row.

However, there are fields tightly fitted on the row that obstruct the onClickListener from being triggered.

I can add an onClickListener to each field to make it work, but is there a better way? Is there a way for the row listener to be triggered through the children?

Comment: Maybe [onInterceptTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) is what you want? Not entirely clear on what you are looking for

Comment: Not sure what the confusion is. Can onInterceptTouchEvent be used when pressing your finger on the row? I'm looking into it but it's not very popular.

Comment: The confusion is, I don't know exactly what you want to be able to do. You say, "I want to add an onClickListener() that does row selection things" which sounds like you want a listener for the entire row. Then you say, "I can add an onClickListener to each field to make it work" which sounds like you set one on each child. I haven't personally used that listener but it should detect when you touch and remove your finger from a child. It was just a suggestion to look into.

Answer (score 0):

If there's nothing in the row that needs to be click, you could try using a list view and just dynamically add rows that way. But items on a listview can't be focused/clicked, only the row itself can be clicked.

Comment: This isn't true. You can click row items in a `ListView`. I do it all the time. Now, whether or not it is a good idea is a matter of opinion.

Comment: I'm not sure of the ListView vs TableLayout, I'll get into it later. For now I would like solutions for TableLayout. :)